# Handling consecutive DynamoDB calls in a node.js Lambda for AWS

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

My example is quite simple.  I am using AWS Lambda in proxy mode where the index.js looks like this.

```
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');
const app = require('./app');

const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app);

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
  return awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context, 'PROMISE').promise;
};
```

I have a separate app.js file which has a POST endpoint.  Inside this endpoint I need to make two queries on a DynamoDB table.

I need to first query the table to determine if something exists.
My code looks like this.

```
// DynamoDB Document Client
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
app.post('/profile/:userSub', (req, res) => {
  const userSub = req.params.userSub;
  const accountName = req.body.accountName; 

  // First query
  const params = {
    TableName: profileTableName,
    IndexName: profileIndexAccountName,
    KeyConditionExpression: 'accountName = :accountName',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':accountName' : accountName
    }
  };

  docClient.query(params, (err, data) => {
    // Process the results
     
  });
}
```

The problem is that I want to do a follow up query `docClient.put` based on the results from the first query.

I don't understand how to chain the queries together so that the first one is completed before the second one is executed.

Can someone please point me to an example? Or alternatively, if there's a better using async/await then I'm happy to follow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** prefer the SDK's async-await patterns.

Here is an example of consecutive [async-await calls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/index.html#asyncawait) using the [AWS SDK for JavaScript v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html).<sup>*</sup>. Note the `async` keyword in the function signature and the `await` keyword before the promise-returning method calls. The docs have the complete [client initialization code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_lib_dynamodb.html#usage).

```js
// myLambda.js
import { DynamoDBDocument } from '@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb';

// ... configure client

const ddbDocClient = DynamoDBDocument.from(client);

export async function handler(event) {
  // ... other stuff

  const getResult = await ddbDocClient.get({ TableName, Key });

  const putResult = await ddbDocClient.put({
    TableName,
    Item: { id: '2', content: getResult.Item.Name },
  });
}
```

---

* The [@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb library's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_lib_dynamodb.html) `DynamoDBDocument` is the v3 equivalent of the v2 client in your code. It exposes convenience methods like `.get` and `.put`.  It also helps convert between native js types and DynamoDB attribute values.

Comment: Thanks. Does the examples include with serverless express and with the index.js file? I just want to make certain if I’m swapping to it I understand the handler code properly.

Comment: No.  It just answers the questions in the OP.